# Prove that the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_{n+1} - a_n |$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Assume that $a_n \longrightarrow a \neq 0$. Prove that the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_{n+1} - a_n |$ converges.

Proof:

Since $(a_n)$ converges, we have that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. That is, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \, N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t: $|a_m - a_n | < \epsilon$ whenever $m > n > N$. Or, equivalently, $|a_{n+1} - a_n | < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. Take $\epsilon := \frac{\epsilon}{(m-n)}$.

Then, $|a_m - a_n| \leq |a_m - a_{m-1}| + \cdots + |a_{n+1} - a_n| < \frac{(m-n)\epsilon}{(m-n)} = \epsilon.$

Hence, $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_{n+1} - a_n |$ converges. QED.

How did I do?

EDIT: Okay, didn't exactly post the full question... It is:

Assume that $a_n \longrightarrow a \neq 0$. Prove that the two series $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_{n+1} - a_n |$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} |\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} |$ either both converge or both diverge.

I managed to show that

$\left(\frac{2}{3 |a|}\right)^2 |a_n - a_{n+1}| < \frac{|a_n - a_{n+1}|}{|a_n| \, |a_{n+1}|} < \left(\frac{2}{|a|}\right)^2 |a_n - a_{n+1}|$.

I thought that $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_{n+1} - a_n |$ would converge and so the sum of $\frac{|a_n - a_{n+1}|}{|a_n| \, |a_{n+1}|} \equiv |\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} |$ would converge by the Comparison Test.

Comment: Are you sure these are all of the assumptions? Because $a_n = a + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ satisfies your hypothesis, but $\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}{|a_{n+1}-a_n|}$ diverges.

Comment: So is it true that $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_{n+1} - a_n|$ diverges?

Comment: Not necessarily, take $a_n =1$ for all $n$. @JoeyZou gave a counterexample for your hypotheses . . . I think something is missing

Comment: This problem has appeared is problem sets for two different professors (one I had in the past, and the other I didn't have but found it online). In both problem sets, the problem was stated as given in my edit. Neither mentioned an additional hypothesis. In fact, both showed in their solution that the second series is bounded above and below by some factor of the first series. Both concluded the proof saying that the result follows from the comparison test, but gave no further explanation.

Comment: There exists a $N$ such that for $n\geq N$, your inequalities after "I managed " are true  (simply use that $|a_n||a_{n+1}|\to |a|^2>0$ and $9a^2/4>a^2>a^2/4$) and so, using the comparison test in two ways show the result.

Comment: @Kelenner do you mean like in the sense of the squeeze theorem? Since one of the sums is bounded above and below it must converge, and so both sums converge??

Comment: Put $u_n=|a_{n+1}-a_n|$, $v_n=1/a_{n+1}-1/a_n|$. You have that for $n\geq N$, $ (4/(9a^2))u_n\leq v_n\leq (4/a^2)u_n$. So: If the serie $u_n$ is convergent, as $v_n\leq (4/a^2)u_n$, the comparison test show that the serie $v_n$ is convergent. Now if the series $v_n$ is convergent... I think that you can take it from here.

Comment: @Kelenner I see what you're saying now but isn't that sort of a cyclic argument? If $u_n$ converges, then $v_n$ converges by the comparison test. Then if $v_n$ converges, then $u_n$ converges (also by the comparison test)—that is what we started with. Also the issue I have been facing is to prove exactly that the series $u_n$ converges. It seems like my originally proposed proof does not work.

Comment: @Kelenner I think it can only be shown one of the two ways: either $u_n$ converges and then $v_n$ converges by the comparison test, OR, $u_n$ diverges and then $v_n$ also diverges (since the sum of $u_n$ has the sum of $v_n$ as an upper bound).

Comment: I think that there is cases with $u_n$ convergent, and cases whith $u_n$  divergent. But what you are asked is to prove: If $u_n$ is convergent, then it is also the case for $v_n$; and if $u_n$ is divergent, then it is also the case for $v_n$, (and  the same inverting the role of $u_n$ and $v_n$) and I think that it is done by the inequalities, and the comparison test.

Comment: Ohhhhh I understand now. I guess I didn't fully understand the question...I think you are right. The question says to prove that either both sums converge or diverge. So (1) if $u_n$ converges, then $v_n$ converges by the comparison test. OR, (2) if $u_n$ diverges, then $v_n$ diverges. So both series will either converge or diverge. I thought I was being asked to definitively prove if the sums converged or not. I got it now, thanks! If you want to write that up as an answer I will accept :)